En Java no se crea el fichero en el directorio correcto
He creado la siguiente clase para crear un fichero en un directorio determinado:
public class CrearFichero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        String directorioPath = "/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/Temp";
        String ficheroPrueba = "ficheroPrueba.txt";
        File directorio = new File(directorioPath);
        File fichero = new File(ficheroPrueba);
        
        try {
            if(!directorio.exists()){
                directorio.mkdirs();
            }
            
            if(!fichero.exists()) {
                fichero.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("Fichero creado con exito");
            } else {
                System.out.println("El fichero ya existe");
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        

    }

}

Siendo el directorio así:

X:/AplicacionJava/ModuloJava/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/Temp

El problema es que se me crea en

X:/AplicacionJava/ModuloJava/


El problema es que estás probando dos rutas separadas y pretendiendo que la JVM sepa que tienen que estar relacionados. La ruta de tu segundo objeto File debería ser la SUMA de ambas rutas ("/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/Temp/ficheroPrueba.txt")! No solo la segunda parte. Si no le indicas la parte inicial tomará como base la ruta desde la cual se está ejecutando tu programa.

Gracias he puesto al final File fichero = new File(directorio, ficheroPrueba); y ha funcionado

Aunque ya haya pasado un buen tiempo, no olvides colocar como respuesta lo que ha respondido a tu pregunta, y aceptarla. No olvides además aceptar las respuestas que te han sido más útiles en tus anteriores preguntas.

El problema es que stas creando el archivo fuera del directorio que especificas: "/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/Temp"
debes crear el archivo especificando el directorio donde se ubicara:
    ...
    ...
    String directorioPath = "/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/Temp";
    String ficheroPrueba = "ficheroPrueba.txt";
    File directorio = new File(directorioPath);
    //File fichero = new File(ficheroPrueba); //* Incorrecto
    
    File fichero = new File(directorio, ficheroPrueba); //* Define el archivo y el directorio.
    ...
    ...

